# Get dynamically created table html with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am generating a table dynamically which html code comes from database. 
The table contains several text inputs. After inputs filled by user, i want to get the outer html of table to save it to the database. When i get the table html with jquery, none of the inputs has the value that entered by user.

I have tried to get the table with values such like that;

```
$(document).on("click", '.btnSaveAnswer', function () {
var  tableHtml = $("#dynamicTable").prop('outerHTML');
});
```

The code above produces this html code;

```
<table>
<tr>
<td nowrap="nowrap" style="font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 15px; color:#000000; text-align: left; "><input type="text" value=""></td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" style="font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 15px; color:#000000; text-align: left; "><input style="width:35px" type="text"></td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" style="font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 15px; color:#000000; text-align: left; "><input style="width:60px" type="text"></td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" style="font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 15px; color:#000000; text-align: left; "><input style="width:50px" type="text"></td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" style="font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 15px; color:#000000; text-align: left; "><input style="width:50px" type="text"></td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" style="font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 15px; color:#000000; text-align: left; "><input style="width:50px" type="text"></td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" style="font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 15px; color:#000000; text-align: left; "><input style="width:70px" type="text"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I was expecting to get the html which input values filled by user exists.

I am aware of such questions exists but most of them about creating table, not getting the html of dynamically created table.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason for why you want to store the entire HTML of that table in a database? Usually only the relevant data (like the user's input) is stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure why you want to store a full set of html instead of the value, but you have two ways to achieve that :

Either replace the inputs by contenteditable divs;

Or first edit the prop value of inputs :

```
$(document).on("click", '.btnSaveAnswer', function () {
    $.each("#dynamicTable input", function() { $(this).prop('value',$(this).val()); });
    var  tableHtml = $("#dynamicTable").prop('outerHTML');
});
```

Comment: idk why but i changed prop to attr and it worked. 
well its a dynamic table in dynamic form. bad practice. i am doing things that i regret later.
Thanks anyway.